# hunspell match words with apostrophe

Tags: openoffice-writer, hunspell

How can I make OpenOffice find words with initial and final apostrophe like: 'sa and int' but not sa or int?

OpenOffice seems to exclude the apostrophe from the word, returning a non-match for 'sa (in fact it matches sa, that is a bad word).

I have tried including BREAK 0 in the aff file without success.

I have tried with WORDCHARS '‘’ without success.

I have the following rules in the aff file:

PFX a Y 1

PFX a kò ' kò

SFX b Y 1

SFX b é ' inté

And the following words in the dictionary:

kòsa/a

inté/b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why the Unicode standard is important.  The [U+0027](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm) apostrophe character is punctuation, not intended to be part of a word.  Use the word-forming code point [U+02BC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2bc/index.htm) instead.

Replace the character in the document as well as in the dictionary and affix files.

Comment: This also happens in italian for words like `dell'`, or `sull'` where the apostrophe is at the end. How to handle that in the `.aff` file?